# How to call a nodejs async function from napi native code and wait until the async promise is resolved

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, n-api

I'm trying to call a nodejs async function from c++ that returns a promise that will be fufilled later using napi

```
Napi::Value napiStatus = this->nodejsFunction.Call(someArgs)
```

I want to wait until the promise is finished and get napiStatus to be filled out with the resolved value rather than the handle to the promise. Is there any way to do this? I've gotten this to work when the function is not async and simply returns a value but my current requirements won't let me do that.

Here's an example function in JS that I want to call

```
function timedTest() {
  let timerExpired = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
      resolve(1);
    },3000)
  })
  return timerExpired;
}
```

I want napiStatus to be the resolved value of 1 (after napi conversions).

Comment: Does this question help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62214214/how-to-create-async-function-using-napi-that-return-promises

Comment: In that example their functions are all C++ based including where the promise is first created. I've been able able to make deferred promise objects in c++ and use them in javascript or in other c++ areas like worker threads, but what i'm trying to do now is have the promise created and resolved in javascript and get that resolved value to propagate back to my c++ function

Answer (score 2):

You have to do the same as if you were doing it from JavaScript: call the `.then()` method of the Promise and register a callback.

Here is the complete example:

```cpp
Napi::Value ret = asyncFunction.Call({});
if (!ret.IsPromise())
  throw Napi::Error::New(env, "your function did not return a Promise");
Napi::Promise promise = ret.As<Napi::Promise>();

Napi::Value thenValue = promise.Get("then");
if (!thenValue.IsFunction())
  throw Napi::Error::New(env, "Promise is not thenable");
Napi::Function then = thenValue.As<Napi::Function>();

Napi::Function callback = Napi::Function::New(env, Callback, "cpp_callback");
then.Call(promise, {callback});
```

The `Callback` function will receive the data from the resolved Promise:

```cpp
Napi::Value Callback(const Napi::CallbackInfo &info) { 
  printf("Callback called\n");
  printf("Data: %s\n", info[0].ToString().Utf8Value().c_str());
  return info.Env().Null();
}
```